# Mysql how to update multiple records without specifying foreignkey value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have a tables that looks like the following:

```
Table - order
id purchase_order_item_id amount
1  1324                   0.0
2  2435                   50.2
3  5643                   87.2
4  6475                   0.0

Table - purchase_order_item
id                     item_id
1324                   82
2435                   83
5643                   84
6475                   85

Table - item
id                     amount
82                   76.1
83                   50.2
84                   87.2
85                   65.9
```

Now I want to check if Order table is having value 0.0 for amount. In this case I have to get amount data from table item (Order->purchase_order_item->item) and update in order table.

I have written below update query which is not running.Trying to correct it.

```
UPDATE order
INNER JOIN purchase_order_item ON purchase_order_item.id =     order.purchase_order_item_id
SET 
order.amount= 
(
SELECT item.amount from item
INNER JOIN purchase_order_item ON purchase_order_item.item_id=item.id
)
where order.amount=0.0;
```

I am new in mysql query and trying to write correct update query.

Comment: Replace tables structures descriptions with their CREATE TABLE scripts. Give some example data as INSERT INTO scripts. Show desired result for this sample data as table-formatted text.

Comment: what exact columns are linked between table2 and table3 via foreign key? Re-write your question in a clear example and provide sample data.

Comment: @t1f There is a foreignkey exists in table T1 which links T1 with T2.

Comment: T2.t2id is not a valid column name please add the create table scripts.(show create table <tablename>)

Comment: Do you have some aversion to providing the create table scripts? Voting to close.

Comment: @P.Salmon I am sorry for not to providing sufficient details. Adding shortly.

Comment: @SSingh https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Order is a reserved word please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql and if there is an error in your query show it don't just say 'which is not running' AND do you really have purchase_order_item with no quantity and only ever 1 per order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want the `update ... join` syntax:

```
update orders o
inner join purchase_order_items poi on poi.id = p.purchas_order_item_id
inner join items i on i.id = poi.item_id
set o.amount = i.amount
where o.amount = 0
```

Side note: `order` is a reserved word in MySQL (as for other databases), so I renamed the table to `orders` (I pluralized other table names too to make it consistent).

Comment: Err ORDER is a reserved word backticks required.

Comment: @P.Salmon: I usually take the table names as quite hypothetical, but sure you are right. I modified my answer.

Comment: @GMB Your query doesn't give any error but it doesn't update records. I am getting  message.        # MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: @GMB Although I am getting message. # MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows) but when I look into table field values, it actually updates.